# Issue while saving python traceback exception in db using Query

Tags: python, exception

In my script if any exception raised i am trying to save in to database using query

```
try:

<-- Code raise Exception -->

except Exception ,e: #Not sure which exception will get thrown
   saveToDB({'error_info':exc_info()[1]}, id=1)

def saveToDB(exp, id):
    vals = ','.join(["%s='%s'" %(k,v) for k,v in exp.iteritems()])
    query = "update trace_redo_lines set %s where id=%s" % (vals , id)
    res = cr.execute(query)
```

after executing the suppose exeption is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto.py", line 22, in Upload
    with open(self.log_path,'r') as out:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Z:\\Doc\\temp.txt'
```

while debugging i found the exception print on cmd is as bellow

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Z:\\Doc\\temp.txt'

so now i am passing this exception in function saveToDB() but while saving the query raise error that

```
*** ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '\\'. (102) (SQLE
cDirectW)")
```

so i am not able to make the exception in proper format so that it can get into db safely.

Is their any workaround to format exception easily to save db.

Driver: pyodbc, python 2.6

Thanks to all.

Comment: Now added in question its a pyodbc

Comment: So what would happen if you have a file called `;CREATE USER megahax0r; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO megahax0r;.txt`? :)

Comment: @Sergey actually its not matter of permission of file the execption can be any thing but issue is while inserting in db using query thanks :)

Comment: @Sashi: I just demonstrated that manually concatenating an SQL query from bits which include data which comes from outside word (user input, filenames etc.) is a sure way to make your code vulnerable to SQL injection. In your example, any exception error message will be able to run arbitrary SQL queries in the database. This is especially important in a web application. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection - see jdi answer for a solution.

Comment: i have find a bit a lousy workaround                             {'error_info':'''%s''' % traceback.format_exc().splitlines()[-1]}

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the `pyodbc` driver, but I wanted to offer a suggestion...

You should try using the proper approach to parameterizing your query, and letting the driver possibly escape your string:

```
query = "update trace_redo_lines set ? where id=?"
res = cr.execute(query, vals, id)
```

Don't use the python string formatting. Pass them as params to the driver. I don't know if `pyodbc` escapes the vals or not but its worth a try.

**Update**

I realized you are joining a bunch of key/value pairs in your string formatting. You can try replacing that with something that joins "key=?", and then add the values to the args:

```
keys = ', '.join(["%s=?" % k for k in exp.iterkeys()])
query = "update trace_redo_lines set %s where id=?" % keys
res = cr.execute(query, *exp.values(), id)
```

You end up building your "key=?" for every key, and then you pass the values to match as params, followed by the id.

Comment: actualy the vals is hodling the values like "error_info="'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Z:\\Doc\\temp.txt''" like this hope it will get resolve with this approach let me try

Comment: You are right but the issue is that the values after set ? are coming from dict so they can be any thing so i have kept the generic in function so its not able to execute query using above suggestion i cant fix the values after 'Set'

Comment: Oh thats right yes. Well you need to put the field names in the string and then use "?" for the values passed as args. I thinkthat really is your issue. Its a problem with the query not escaping the backslash.

Comment: You can fix it by joining key=? in your list comp join, and then pass the exp.values() as param args

Comment: i tried using the above format too but it showing error :
*** NotSupportedError: ('Python type exceptions.IOError not supported.  param=3', 'HY097')   the parm 3 is the Exception message

Comment: i have find a bit a lousy workaround {'error_info':'''%s''' % traceback.format_exc().splitlines()[-1]}